# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2). What went wrong?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I got this code from online. Can someone help me what went wrong?
Here's the snippet where the error popped up:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(Nucleus_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
pad_del = np.zeros_like(Nucleus_img)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The CV2 [findCountours](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) function return 2 values, not 3. They are *contours* and *hierarchy*.

Change your code, for example:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(...)
```

Comment: question is a duplicate and should be flagged as such, but not answered.